# Analyse what caused a pagesplit afterwards?

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, page-splits

Ok normally we have 0-20 page splits per second, but last night it spiked to ~500.

Now is there any way to figure out what caused it?

I know i can run the following to find mid page splits but it doesn't go that far back.

```
SELECT COUNT(1) AS NumberOfSplits, AllocUnitName, Context FROM fn_dblog(NULL,NULL) WHERE Operation = 'LOP_DELETE_SPLIT' GROUP BY AllocUnitName, Context ORDER BY NumberOfSplits DESC
```

I have both full backups and log backups if that helps?

Answer (score 1):

I must say first that using fn_dblog and fn_dump_dblog is unsupported as these commands are not supported by Microsoft. Jonathan Kehayias in his article even pointed out that using fn_dump_dblog multiple times has grave performance implication so use these undocumented commands on your own risk. There is also a way to track page splits, not perfectly though but will help, using DMV [Sys.dm_db_index_operational_stats](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174281.aspx) the columns leaf_allocation_count in output points to page split which occurred for index and nonleaf_allocation_count gives you page allocation due to page splits read the documentation please. You can include object(table) for which you want to track page split by editing the query

Below is the code which may tell you page splits for index and heap does not have page splits they have forwarding pointers

```
select
ios.index_id,
o.name as Object_Name,
i.name as Index_Name, 
ios.leaf_allocation_count as Page_split_for_index,
ios.nonleaf_allocation_count Page_allocation_caused_by_pagesplit
from sys.dm_db_index_operational_stats(DB_ID(N'db_name'),Null,Null,Null) ios
join
sys.indexes i
on
ios.index_id=i.index_id
join
sys.objects o
on 
ios.object_id=o.object_id
where o.type_desc='user_table'
```

Other method is by using Extended events, below link by Jonathan has steps( applicable to SQL 2012 or later)

http://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/jonathan/tracking-problematic-pages-splits-in-sql-server-2012-extended-events-no-really-this-time/

Ofcourse you can read below article by Paul Randal where he showed how to track page split using fn_dblog command

http://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/paul/tracking-page-splits-using-the-transaction-log/

Comment: Is there any way to go backwards in time with this solution or it has to be done as the page splits are happening? thanks for pointing out the performance problem, in my case i did not execute the commands on our production server instead i executed them on my own SQL server and then restarted it when i was done.

Comment: Since DMV information is cumulative from previous SQL server restart so this information do includes all page splits( good and bad) which happened after previous sql server restart. I am not sure what you mean by 'go backwards'. fn_dblog would not be much reliable as log backups truncate the logs and makes VLF reusable so that it can be ownewritten if such VLF is overwritten you cannot get any information from fn_dblog. A more supported way is also by using extended events I have updated Link in my reply.

Comment: Just as you specified fn_dblog loses information when the log is truncated so with fn_dblog i can't go backwards.. anyway thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

After trail and error i managed to use the following sql to find the reason.

```
SELECT OBJECT_NAME(p.object_id), i.name, COUNT(dblog.AllocUnitId) [count] FROM sys.partitions p
LEFT JOIN sys.indexes i ON i.object_id = p.object_id AND i.index_id = p.index_id
INNER JOIN sys.allocation_units au ON au.container_id = p.hobt_id
INNER JOIN fn_dump_dblog (
        NULL, NULL, N'DISK', 1, N'C:\Backup\database_2014_07_16_200004_0031102.trn',
        DEFAULT, DEFAULT, DEFAULT, DEFAULT, DEFAULT, DEFAULT, DEFAULT,
        DEFAULT, DEFAULT, DEFAULT, DEFAULT, DEFAULT, DEFAULT, DEFAULT,
        DEFAULT, DEFAULT, DEFAULT, DEFAULT, DEFAULT, DEFAULT, DEFAULT,
        DEFAULT, DEFAULT, DEFAULT, DEFAULT, DEFAULT, DEFAULT, DEFAULT,
        DEFAULT, DEFAULT, DEFAULT, DEFAULT, DEFAULT, DEFAULT, DEFAULT,
        DEFAULT, DEFAULT, DEFAULT, DEFAULT, DEFAULT, DEFAULT, DEFAULT,
        DEFAULT, DEFAULT, DEFAULT, DEFAULT, DEFAULT, DEFAULT, DEFAULT,
        DEFAULT, DEFAULT, DEFAULT, DEFAULT, DEFAULT, DEFAULT, DEFAULT,
        DEFAULT, DEFAULT, DEFAULT, DEFAULT, DEFAULT, DEFAULT, DEFAULT) dblog ON dblog.AllocUnitId = au.allocation_unit_id
        WHERE dblog.Operation = 'LOP_DELETE_SPLIT' AND au.type = 1
        GROUP BY i.name, p.object_id
        ORDER BY COUNT(dblog.AllocUnitId) DESC
```

Edit: as pointed out by @Shanky don't run this in production it could result in performance problems that could require a restart of the SQL Server